# Norm of the $ \Gamma$-invariant functions

Tags: group-theory, normed-spaces

Consider a function $ f(x) $ on $F^*_p$ and $\Gamma \subseteq F^*_p$ is a subgroup.

The function is $ \Gamma$-invariant, meaning $ f(\gamma x) = f(x) $ for all $\gamma \in\Gamma$.

I'm reading the paper that says that due to the $ \Gamma$-invariance of the function, its 1-norm is

$$ \lVert f \rVert _1 = \sum_x f(x) = \vert \Gamma \vert \cdot \sum_{\psi \in F^*_p / \Gamma} f(\psi) $$

I don't understand how that equation came to be, considering that the $ F^*_p / \Gamma $ part doesn't seem to mean "quotient group". What meaning can $ F^*_p / \Gamma $ have in this context?

Comment: It is the quotient group. $f(\Gamma x)$ is well-defined and $\sum_y |f(y)|= |\Gamma|\sum_{\Gamma x\in F_p^*/\Gamma} |f(\Gamma x)|$

Comment: @reuns oh, honestly it's getting clearer, thanks for responding! Sorry, I'm feeling very dumb, but I guess I don't understand how $ f(\Gamma x) $ is defined. $ \Gamma x $ is a coset (i.e. a set) and $ f $ is defined for $ x \in F^*_p $ (i.e. integers). Does $ f(\Gamma x) $ act on a coset representative? Please do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: $f$ is constant on $\Gamma x$ so we set $f(\Gamma x)=f(x)$

Comment: @reuns thank you so much, this was very helpful! Would you like to post your comments as an answer so I can accept it?